# Trigger transition between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transition

### Backstory

I am trying to achieve a similar affect as this one with React: https://youtu.be/OnlF8sKQRsY. Since I've never done any transitions nor animations I've done some research about transitions and animations with React and found many ways of doing those.

I've found a library called Pose, https://popmotion.io/pose/, which looks really good and offers many ways of creating transitions. I am using that right now, but I can change if someone tips me.

### What I wonder

How can I trigger my transition when I'm on the component I want to "transition away"? I got this right now:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {!this.state.renderStartScreen && (
      <ExpressCheckout whereToEat={whereToEat} />
    )}
    {this.state.renderStartScreen && (
      <StartScreen
        hide={!renderStartScreen}
        startExpressCheckout={this.startExpressCheckout}
      />
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

`StartScreen` is the component I'm currently on and `ExpressCheckout` is the component I want to transition to. `renderStartScreen` is coming from my state which value can be changed from a button in `StartScreen`.

In `ExpressCheckout` I've managed to create a transition where my UI slides from the left to right with Pose.

```
const Box = posed.div({
  left: { x: 1000 },
  right: {
    x: -500,
    transition: {
      duration: 1500
    }
  }
});


return (
    <Grid
    style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "#FFF", marginTop: "2em" }}
    >
    <Box className="box" pose={this.state.animate ? "right" : "left"}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>EXPRESS</h1>
    </Box>
    </Grid>
);
```

But when it comes to trigger the transition for transitioning away from `StartScreen` I have no clue how to do so. And I am not even sure if I'm on the right path right now. Any help is much appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After reading a lot on Pose's own docs I managed to solve my issue.

So this is my way of transitioning between components in React with Pose.

Hope it helps someone in the future!

https://codesandbox.io/s/5x2mpq1ljl